# How to show own list of properties on google maps like booking.com

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing the maps using Google Map API, is there any API or examples can help me to complete something like booking.com?

Booking.com search by Map View function will show their list of properties... What should I do? And how to keep update the maps when user drag from one point to another and the maps will show the properties within the maps?

[Booking.com search hotels by Map View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DXIO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make:
1) a call to your server for locations 
2) store all location on the client and render it as a marker. here's an example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex
3) then you can add a click event handler for each marker, here you can find how https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Then you need to customize all as you prefer.

Comment: whether the google map api can show all the list of my properties on the maps when I move the maps? Cheers

Comment: Yes, but not the map api, the map itself will store all objects once you add them to it. The only way to manipulate with created objects is to save them somewhere on the page in js. Otherwise you will not being able to do with them anything.

Comment: Cheers mate, will try to do it.